# How can I pass a ListView contaning imageView and textView to other Activity

Tags: java, android, listview, mobile

I have 2 different activities but both of them has a **listview**. My first activity is empty in terms of data. It just has a button for passing to my second activity.

Each row contains one imageView, textView and checkBox in my second activity. 
When I make the checkbox active in my second activity any row, I want to send data to my first activity. For example, I click a checkbox for selecting a line, and when I back in first activity, I should see this line (with ImageView, TextView). Actually, in addition, I want to delete data in first activity when checkbox isn't active. However, I am thinking that I can find this solution if you help me for my first question.

MY FIRST ACTIVITY (I should see rows in here)

```
   ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Bundle bundleObject = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundleObject != null) {
        String resultText = bundleObject.getString("RESULT_TEXT");
        dbHelper.insertNewTask(resultText);
        byte[] byteArray = bundleObject.getByteArray("picture");
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
        image.setImageBitmap(b); //ERROR IS HERE!!!!! IT ISN'T WORKING
```

MY SECOND ACTIVITY

```
    byte[] byteArray;
    Bitmap bmp;
    int[] images = {R.drawable.book, R.drawable.watchingtv};
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.book);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byteArray  = stream.toByteArray();
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context context;
    int[] images;
    String[] mytitles;

    MyAdapter(Context c, String[] titles, int images[]) {
        super(c, R.layout.row_2, R.id.newTaskTitle, titles);
        this.context = c;
        this.images = images;
        this.mytitles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_2, parent, false);
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.newImage);

        final TextView myTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.newTaskTitle);
        myImage.setImageResource(images[position]);
        myTitle.setText(mytitles[position]);
        checkBox = (CheckBox) row.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Boolean durum = checkBox.isChecked();
                if(durum=true){
                    Intent intent = new Intent (dinlenmeEkrani_newOptions.this, dinlenmeEkrani.class);
                    intent.putExtra("picture", byteArray);
                    intent.putExtra("RESULT_TEXT", myTitle.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);

                }
                else{

                }

            }

        });
        return row;
    }
```

*Second activity might has mistakes. When I try to reach the solution, I might do some mistakes.*

**I want to say these : I have succeeded in terms of passing textview. So, When I delete some codes related to Image (especially in my first activity), I see passing textView which is coming from String.xml. And also, I just have tried R.Drawable.book because if it works, I think that I can add others drawables.**

(if you wonder dbHelper, it is here)

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper
public static final String DB_TABLE = "Task";
public static final String DB_COLUMN =  "TaskName";
public void insertNewTask (String task){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DB_COLUMN,task);
        db.insertWithOnConflict(DB_TABLE,null,values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried sending the image as string instead of bytearray?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't possible to share any view object between activities, because their are linked with the Activity and Activities are completely independent. You need to create a logic to identify and deal with states just passing small pieces of data between activities, like you are already doing with the intent.